# How to store a web page/ data from web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I would like to store this page [Tableau Public Gallery feed](https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/feed) locally in a JSON format using JavaScript. I have looked for scripts and code snippets but I am unable to find anything helpful since every time I run the code I get the same error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/feed' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Below is the code I am using currently.

```
  $.ajax({

     url:"https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/feed",
     method: 'GET',
     dataType:'JSON',
     headers: {
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
     },
     success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
     }
});
```

Also I have tried using POSTMAN. It also gives the error that Could not get any response. Is it because of the restriction from the Tableau website or am I doing something wrong.

*PS: I am trying to implement this in Angular 7 project.*

Comment: The server needs to have CORS enabled in order for the mentioned code in question to work. I believe they have not done that.

Comment: Also, it is not a very good idea to use `$.ajax` in angular 7 project. You might want to consider making a service which could make that call for you :) https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 This might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/feed provides a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response, you will not be able to do this from a different domain on the browser. What I'd recommend instead is to set up a backend end point (maybe through NodeJS) which calls this instead of the front end and then call that endpoint from your code. In the back end you will not face the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error which is why I recommend that as your proxy.

If you decide to use NodeJS as your backend you can do the following:

Run `npm install --save express` to install Express for Node (A Node server framework)

Create a structure like so:

### [image]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/tableau-gallery-feed",
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express')
var https = require('https')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/api/tableau-gallery-feed', function (req, res) {
    https.get('https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/feed', function (data) {
        data.setEncoding('utf8')
        let rawData = ''
        data.on('data', function (chunk) {
            rawData += chunk
        })
        data.on('end', function () {
            res.end(rawData)
        });
    })
})

app.listen(8888, () => console.log('Server started.'))
```

Then run `node index.js` to start your server

Go to localhost:8888 to see your page and if you check the console the data should be logged.

Comment: Can you please share an example for the same.

Comment: Are you using NodeJS as your backend @Bhartendu?

Comment: I have installed node and npm but I am not using them for anything else other than the installation and dependencies of angular-cli

Comment: You cannot do it directly from client side by JS, you need to build server side(Like node as @Talha mentioned) utility that will accept URLs data and send results back to your angular 7 app. Also, I'm not sure about this but I can think of scraping the data too if nothing works. In case if you will be using node as a backend then https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio (Cheerio) will be a great help.

Comment: @Bhartendu I just updated the answer with a very simple Node Express Server example.